# Elixir - Read postgres result

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I need to read the raw Postgres output and iterate over the row value.

```
ww = %Postgrex.Result{columns: ["id", "tracking_link"], command: :select,
 connection_id: 22311, num_rows: 14,
 rows: [[2, "http://StarChef.com?id=1"],
  [3, "http://CaptainAmerica:TWSLiveWP.com?id=2"]]}
```

ww[:rows] - not giving output

Comment: try it this way -> ww.rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.` to access fields of a struct. The bracket syntax only works for maps which are not structs or structs which implement the `Access` behavior.

```
iex(1)> ww = %Postgrex.Result{columns: ["id", "tracking_link"], command: :select,
...(1)>  connection_id: 22311, num_rows: 14,
...(1)>  rows: [[2, "http://StarChef.com?id=1"],
...(1)>   [3, "http://CaptainAmerica:TWSLiveWP.com?id=2"]]}
%Postgrex.Result{columns: ["id", "tracking_link"], command: :select,
 connection_id: 22311, num_rows: 14,
 rows: [[2, "http://StarChef.com?id=1"],
  [3, "http://CaptainAmerica:TWSLiveWP.com?id=2"]]}
iex(2)> ww.rows
[[2, "http://StarChef.com?id=1"],
 [3, "http://CaptainAmerica:TWSLiveWP.com?id=2"]]
```